# Follow up - Sampling random row from data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, sample

I had asked a question on sampling from a list for which a solution was provided. This is a follow up

My problem has 2 steps. I would like to sample a number of rows (3) from a data frame and then take a second sample (1 row) which is not in the first sample.

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=10))
( samples <- sample(nrow(df), size = 4) )
# [1] 6 8 4 9
sample_1 <- df[ samples[-1], ]
sample_2 <- df[ samples[1],,drop = FALSE ]
sample_1
#            X1         X2
# 8 -0.09465904 -2.6564554
# 4  0.63286260 -0.2787888
# 9  2.01842371 -2.4404669
sample_2
#           X1        X2
# 6 -0.1061245 0.6359504
```

Is there a way to build this in a loop such that when the first iteration is done, the second sample does not include data from the first sample.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in loop? Do you want to build multiple such pairs of dataframes?

Comment: Hi Ronak Shah, yes that was the intention

Answer (score 0):

We can use a `for` loop to update the dataset on each iteration while return

```
df1 <- df
sizevec <- c(3, 1)
lst1 <- vector('list', 2)
for(i in seq_along(lst1)) {
      samples <- sample(nrow(df1), size = sizevec[i]) 
      lst1[[i]] <- df1[samples,, drop = FALSE]
      df1 <- df1[-samples,, drop = FALSE]
  }
```

-output

```
lst1
#[[1]]
#          X1         X2
#2 -0.5646982  2.2866454
#5  0.4042683 -0.1333213
#4  0.6328626 -0.2787888

#[[2]]
#         X1        X2
#3 0.3631284 -1.388861
```

Comment: Thank you akrun. This solution is useful. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You easily could do this by sampling the rows of your data frame and make a `matrix` out of it with 3 + 1 rows. This might yield duplicates at the end if `nrow(df) %% 4 == 0` is `FALSE` because of recycling. We can eliminate the `duplicated` by setting them to `NA`.

```
set.seed(42)
m <- matrix(sample(1:nrow(df)), 4)
m[duplicated(as.vector(m))] <- NA
m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    7
# [2,]    5    4    3
# [3,]   10    6   NA
# [4,]    8    9   NA
```

Now we `apply` ordinary subsetting to the columns of `m`, using first row values for the single sample and the rest for the fourfould one. Naturally, if `nrow(df)` is not divisible by four, the `NA`s in `m` result in smaller or zero fourfould samples.

```
res <- setNames(
  apply(m, 2, function(i) list(samp.1=df[na.omit(i[2:4]), ], samp.2=df[i[1], ])), 
  paste0("draw.", seq(ncol(m))))
res
# $draw.1
# $draw.1$samp.1
# X1         X2
# 5   0.40426832 -0.1333213
# 10 -0.06271410  1.3201133
# 8  -0.09465904 -2.6564554
# 
# $draw.1$samp.2
# X1      X2
# 1 1.370958 1.30487
# 
# 
# $draw.2
# $draw.2$samp.1
# X1         X2
# 4  0.6328626 -0.2787888
# 6 -0.1061245  0.6359504
# 9  2.0184237 -2.4404669
# 
# $draw.2$samp.2
# X1       X2
# 2 -0.5646982 2.286645
# 
# 
# $draw.3
# $draw.3$samp.1
# X1        X2
# 3 0.3631284 -1.388861
# 
# $draw.3$samp.2
# X1         X2
# 7 1.511522 -0.2842529
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c(1.37095844714667, -0.564698171396089, 0.363128411337339, 
0.63286260496104, 0.404268323140999, -0.106124516091484, 1.51152199743894, 
-0.0946590384130976, 2.01842371387704, -0.062714099052421), X2 = c(1.30486965422349, 
2.28664539270111, -1.38886070111234, -0.278788766817371, -0.133321336393658, 
0.635950398070074, -0.284252921416072, -2.65645542090478, -2.44046692857552, 
1.32011334573019)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

Comment: Thank you jay.sf. This gives me what I need. Appreciate it!

Comment: Hi @trix, happy to hear that. In this case you may [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).